# Accessing TourArray values in a different activity

Tags: android, arrays, android-activity

I have a requirement that, I am having some description stored in an array list adapter which extends Base Adapter. I want to access these values in a different Activity say TourDescription and want to assign then to the editText in that.

Can any one tell me the solution?

Thanks in advance,

Tejaswi

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? What is starting that other acitvity? Where does the data come from? Is it static or dynamic data?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are having ArrayList and you are passing it to your custom adapter, now you want to get the particular Object and pass it to the TourDescription activity.

So for that you need to write the below code inside the **`getItem()`** method in your adapter.

```
 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemList.get(position);
    }
```